# How to print xterm's dimensions in title bar?

Tags: xterm, window-management, window-title

Is it possible to print xterm's dimensions in title bar? I'd like something simple like `WxH`, which updates whenever the terminal is resized.

Answer (score 6):

You can get xterm's dimensions via the environmental variables `$COLUMNS` and `$LINES`. You can then set the title via certain escape codes documented e.g. [in Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html). Here is a one-off command to set title:

```
# The title text is the stuff between ; and \a
printf "\e]0;${COLUMNS}x${LINES}\a"
```

<del>I don't know if there is a way to update the title when the window is resized.</del> You can then trap the SIGWINCH signal, which xterm sends when the terminal size changes. If you use Bash, put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function update_title {
    printf "\e]0;${COLUMNS}x${LINES}\a"
}

trap -- update_title SIGWINCH
```

*Warning:* I have a feeling that there might some weird interactions caused by this solution. If you notice some terminal applications misbehaving when you resize the window, try disabling the trap above and see if the problem persists.

Comment: So why not put it the prompt?  `export PS1='\[\e]0;${COLUMNS}x${LINES}\a\]...'`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a built-in feature of xterm.

If you're running an interactive shell in that terminal, you can make it update the window title each time it displays a prompt. With all popular shells, the variables `COLUMNS` and `LINES` are updated to reflect the current dimensions of the terminal. You can put the escape sequences to set the window title as part of your prompt (you'll need to tell your shell that the escape sequence has zero width, otherwise the shell will get confused about the position of the cursor), or you can arrange to print the string before displaying a prompt. In bash, to set the window title to the current directory followed by the window size, you can use something like

```
set_term_title () {
  printf '\[\033]2;%s %dx%d\007\]' "$PWD" "$LINES" "$COLUMNS"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND
set_term_title"
```

In zsh:

```
set_term_title () {
  printf '\[\033]2;%s %dx%d\007\]' $PWD $LINES $COLUMNS
}
precmd+=set_term_title
```

If the window is resized while the shell is displaying a prompt, the shell receives a [SIGWINCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGWINCH) signal. Add a handler for that signal.

```
trap set_term_title SIGWINCH
```

If the window is resized while a command is executing, the title will only be updated the next time the shell displays a prompt. Only the foreground process receives a signal in that case, so the shell never finds out, it can only query for updated information when the command is finished or suspending and the shell resumes execution.

If you want the title to be updated independently of what is executing in the terminal, you'll need to rope in some external component. A fancy window manager should be able to do it — but most can't. In sawfish, you can tweak [`rewrite-window-title`](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/sawfish/images/8/8b/Rewrite-window-titles.jl/revision/latest?cb=20070704164557) to add the window dimensions rather than apply a regexp-based transformation.

You can use [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) to obtain the information and change the title:

```
(
  title="$(xdotool getwindowname "$windowid")"
  eval "$(xdotool getwindowgeometry --shell)"
  title="${title% *} ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}"
  xdotool set_window --name "$title" "$windowid"
)
```

Note that `xdotool getwindowgeometry` returns dimensions in pixels, not in characters. I don't know how to *react* to a window being resized without the cooperation of the window manager.